# How to remove table default attributes of tiny mce plugin

Tags: tinymce

I can customize the default attribute of table using the following code:

```
 tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
      plugins: "table",
      menubar: "table",
      toolbar: "table",
      table_default_attributes: {
        border: '1'
      }
    });
```

For this code table will be look like: `<table border="1">`. Now if I want to change this border value, I can. Pretty simple. But if I want to completely remove this attribute, how can I? Meaning I want a table without any attribute like: `<table>` only. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two TinyMCE configuration options to set the default styles and attributes that are placed on a table:

```
table_default_styles: {},
table_default_attributes: {},
```

Details on these can be found on the documentation page for the table plugin:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/table/#table_default_attributes

Here is an example (on TinyMCE Fiddle):

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Fvgaab

Comment: I have to use php code. So I have to use $settings['table_default_styles'] = json_encode(array()); but json_encode(array() generates [].

Comment: Why can you not pass an empty set of braces (an empty object) via PHP?  You are not expected to pass in an array.